# caesar cipher check in ocaml

Tags: string, ocaml, substring

I want to implement a check function that given two strings `s1` and `s2` will check if `s2` is the `caesar cipher of s1` or not. the inter face needs to be looked like `string->string->bool`.

the problem is that I am not allowed to use any string functions other than `String.length`, so how can I solve it? i am not permitted any `list array`, `iterations`. Only `recursions` and `pattern matching`.

Please help me. And also can you tell me how I can write a substring function in ocaml other than the module function with the above restrictions?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @pad and  i gave the code in my answer since character is limited.      let check s1 s2=
 (* alphabet mapping table*)
 string key="ABCD"
 (*mapping*)
 string mapping_cipher="CADB"
 if String.length s1 != String.length s2
  raise exception;
 else
  match s1.[0] with

Comment: (*some letter in the key string and get the index i from the key string and match s2.[0] with mapping_cipher.[i], can i write some function & call here? will be appropriate?@chrisaycock
  
  *)
  
  (*how can I navigate through the string key recursively without particular string function and iteration?
  for example how can I do it maintaining the format string->string->bool?
  and also if i call recursively how can i call the recursive function with rest of s1 and s2 if string.sub is not allowed? 
  and I dont know even s1.[0] will be legal because it also a string manipulation.
  
  
  *)

Comment: Are you asking two separate questions? (1. how to write the caesar cipher check function and 2. how to write a substring function) If so you should ask the other one separately.

Comment: You seem to be very confused with types in OCaml. `string -> string -> bool`, to an OCaml programmer, means a function that takes two string arguments and returns a boolean. (Which, due to currying, is actually a one argument function that returns a function that takes the rest of the arguments. If you don't understand this, you need to stop and read about currying.) So I don't see any need to make substrings (all you need to return is a boolean) or make recursive calls or anything like that.

Comment: @newacct let me clarify, if i need to compare two strings with recursion i will have to check first character of one string and first of another than call the function again with the rest of the strings right? in this case i need to have the substrings of the two strings. i cannot use a variable to increase it in each recursive call because the function does not take any integer. so how can  do that?

Comment: He does need recursion, he just doesn't need to build substrings to recurse (although having them would make the code for the main function pretty clean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are probably allowed to use `s.[i]` to get the ith character of string s.  This is the same as String.get, but the instructor may not think of it in those terms.  Without some form of getting the individual characters for the string, I believe that this is impossible.  You should probably double check with your instructor to be sure, but I would be surprised if he had meant for you to be unable to separate a string into characters (which is something that you cannot do with pattern-matching alone in Ocaml).

Once you can get individual characters, the way to do it should be pretty clear (you do not need substring to traverse each string recursively).

If you still want to write substring, creating it would be complex since you don't have access to String.create or other similar functions.  But you can write your own version of String.create using recursion, one character string literals (like `"x"`), the ability to set a character in a string to another (like `s.[0] <- c`), and string concatenation (`s1 ^ s2`).  Again, of course, all of this is assuming that those operators are allowed to be used.

Comment: yah I guess so. but in that case i may not use string.create function for a new substring. I am new to ocaml. without decalring a variable or using an assignemnt  how can i create a substring then?

Comment: That is something that I had not thought of for substring.  (Do note that you don't need substring to answer the main question, although I can certainly see why you'd want it.)  I've amended the answer to address that question.