# Creating own substring functions recursively in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, substring

How can i write a substring function in ocaml without using any assignments lists and iterations, only recursions? i can only use string.length.

i tried so far is

```
let substring s s2 start stop=
if(start < stop) then 
    substring s s2 (start+1) stop
    else s2;;
```

but obviously it is wrong, problem is that how can i pass the string that is being built gradually with recursive calls?

Answer (score 2):

This feels like a homework problem that is intended to teach you think think about recursion.  For me it would be easier to think about the recursion part if you decide on the basic operations you're going to use.  You can't use assignments, lists, or iterations, okay.  You need to extract parts of your input string somehow, but you obviously can't use the built-in substring function to do this, that would defeat the purpose of the exercise.  The only other operation I can think of is the one that extracts a single character from a string:

```
# "abcd".[2];;
- : char = 'c'
```

You also need a way to add a character to a string, giving a longer string.  But you're not allowed to use assignment to do this.  It seems to me you're going to have to use `String.make` to translate your character to a string:

```
# String.make 1 'a';;
- : string = "a"
```

Then you can concatenate two strings using the `^` operator:

```
# "abc" ^ "def"
- : string = "abcdef"
```

Are you allowed to use these three operations?  If so, you can start thinking about the recursion part of the substring problem.  If not, then I probably don't understand the problem well enough yet to give advice.  (Or maybe whoever set up the restrictions didn't expect you to have to calculate substrings?  Usually the restrictions are also a kind of hint as to how you should proceed.)

Moving on to your specific question.  In beginning FP programming, you don't generally want to pass the answer down to recursive calls.  You want to pass a smaller problem down to the recursive call, and get the answer *back* from it.  For the substring problem, an example of a smaller problem is to ask for the substring that starts one character further along in the containing string, and that is one character shorter.

(Later on, you might want to pass partial answers down to your recursive calls in order to get tail-recursive behavior.  I say don't worry about it for now.)

Comment: let me clarify, if i need to compare two strings with recursion i will have to check first character of one string and first of another than call the function again with the rest of the strings right? in this case i need to have the substrings of the two strings. i cannot use a variable to increase it in each recursive call because the function does not take any integer. so how can do that? the function has to the following format string->string->bool.

Comment: This looks like the same question you asked on another page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968171/caesar-cipher-check-in-ocaml  You can use substrings to compare strings recursively.  However, it's also common in FP to define helper functions with whatever parameters you need.

Comment: yes i wrote one function which takes two strings and one integer. the integer is required to recursively going through the string, as substring is not allowed. I then call that function from my original function. I hope this will do. Or i can write a substring function instead i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can't give you the answer to this, Partly because it's your homework, and partly because it's been 3 years since I've touched OCaml syntax, but I could try to help you along.

Now the Basic principle behind recursion is to break a problem down into smaller versions of itself.

You don't pass the string that is slowly being built up, instead use your recursive function to generate a string that is almost built up except for a single character, and then you add that character to the end of the string.

Comment: yes i can build a string such a way, i am new to ocaml but did programming before, but to do this i ned to use string concatenation, i hope it is allowed, but if not then i just want to know if there is other ways possible, if not i will use ^ instead.